# why google chrome is not installing in my Dockerfile

Tags: python, linux, docker, google-chrome

when i was running my docker file there was a error at installing google chrome how to fix it
the code for docker file is

```
FROM python:3.8.5-slim-buster
ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR 1
RUN sed -i.bak 's/us-west-2\.ec2\.//' /etc/apt/sources.list
# Installing Required Packages
RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install --no-install-recommends -y \
    chromium \
    util-linux \

# install google chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

and error is

```
Step 6/12 : RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
 ---> Running in f4cf586966ff
--2020-07-25 18:12:05--  https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
Resolving dl.google.com (dl.google.com)... 172.217.13.238, 2607:f8b0:4004:809::200e
Connecting to dl.google.com (dl.google.com)|172.217.13.238|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 69649616 (66M) [application/x-debian-package]
Saving to: ‘google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb’
2020-07-25 18:12:07 (43.4 MB/s) - ‘google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb’ saved [69649616/69649616]
Removing intermediate container f4cf586966ff
 ---> 697b7e21efea
Step 7/12 : RUN apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
 ---> Running in 6e5858eb9f5d
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
Reading package lists...
E: Unable to mkstemp /tmp/deb-file-google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb.K9fPKY - GetTempFile (2: No such file or directory)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

how to fix this ?

i was trying this google chrome to run my selenium is any alternative way for this

Answer (score 1):

I belive the correct way to install it would be:

`dpkg -i ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb`